# Find all UPnP gateways with miniupnp

Tags: c, networking, upnp, miniupnpc

Discovering gateway devices process using miniupnp is as follows:

1. Call `upnpDiscover(...)` to find all available devices which support UPnP protocol.
2. Call `UPNP_GetValidIGD(...)` to get first gateway from this list.

Is there any solution to get **all** gateways from list, obtained in step 1?

Comment: Why the question is downvoted? Please, explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a [fork](https://github.com/AlexEx54/miniupnp) of miniupnpc. Added routine `GetValidConnectedIGDs`, which returns list of all gateway devices found.